# How to add comment in CSV while using scikit-learn

Tags: csv, scikit-learn, nlp

I am currently doing Natural Language Processing project.

I need to transform the word into vector format for computer to process.

For debugging I need to know the relation between vector and word, so there must be some comment after each row of data.

How to add comment in CSV while using scikit-learn?

Comment: Instead of having a row of comment after the row of data, you can make a column for the comments. And then ignore that column while training the model, and check those values in debugging

Comment: also note that sklearn is not really dealing with CSV-files directly, you'll read them in and can just skip the unnecessary parts at that point.